# How to upgrade kubernetes pause container

Tags: kubernetes, upgrade

When I upgrade kubernetes version 1.20.X to 1.21.1, all containers related is up to date. But the pause container is still in use, I can not force update it to the latest version.

```
# docker ps
XXX/pause:3.2
# docker images
XXX/pause:3.2
XXX/pause:3.4.1
# docker rmi -f XXX/pause:3.2
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete XXX/pause:3.2 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container
```

Comment: `--pod-infra-container-image` (of kubelet)

Comment: Hi, could you please tell more about the update process you've made? Could you also show what `kubelet` arguments are? Specifically the argument that *zerkms* pointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upgrade the cluster using `kubeadm` you will probably get the notification about the `kubelet` manual upgrade requirement:

```
Components that must be upgraded manually after you have upgraded the control plane with 'kubeadm upgrade apply':
COMPONENT   CURRENT       TARGET
kubelet     1 x v1.20.7   v1.21.1
```

I've managed to create a `kubeadm` cluster version: `1.20.7-00` and then upgraded the cluster to the newest available at the time: `1.21.1-00`. After the upgrade was complete, the pause container stayed in the version `3.2.0` even after upgrading `kubelet`.

**One of the ways** to update `kubelet` to use specific `pause` container version is by:

- modifiying following file:

  - `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env` (change for example to `k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.3`)

```sh
KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS="--network-plugin=cni --pod-infra-container-image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2"
```

- restarting kubelet (depending on the OS)

  - `$ systemctl restart kubelet`

After this steps you should be seeing the new version of `pause` container passed to `kubelet`.

- `$ systemctl status kubelet`

```sh
kruk@ubuntu:~$ systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
             └─10-kubeadm.conf
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-05-27 13:28:12 UTC; 7h ago
       Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
   Main PID: 724 (kubelet)
      Tasks: 18 (limit: 9442)
     Memory: 128.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
             └─724 /usr/bin/kubelet <-SKIPPED-> --pod-infra-container-image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.3

May 27 13:29:12 ubuntu kubelet[724]: 2021-05-27 13:29:12.125 [INFO][5164] ipam.go 1068: Successfully claimed IPs: [172.16.243.205/26] block=172.16.243.192/26 handle="k8s-pod-network.1638a3ba44d1a46f6ad7eadb1519a42cdda98fafd0c94a7b67881f38213a5032" host="ubuntu"
May 27 13:29:12 ubuntu kubelet[724]: 2021-05-27 13:29:12.125 [INFO][5164] ipam.go 722: Auto-assigned 1 out of 1 IPv4s: [172.16.243.205/26] handle="k8s-pod-network.1638a3ba44d1a46f6ad7eadb1519a42cdda98fafd0c94a7b67881f38213a5032" host="ubuntu"
May 27 13:29:12 ubuntu kubelet[724]: time="2021-05-27T13:29:12Z" level=info msg="Released host-wide IPAM lock." source="ipam_plugin.go:369"
```

In my testing the old container that were present were not updated to the new `pause` container. They stayed at version `3.2`. Each new workload that was spawned, like for example `nginx` `Deployment` was using new `pause` container version:

- `$ docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS     NAMES
1cc215019335   nginx                  "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 hours ago   Up 8 hours             k8s_nginx_nginx-6799fc88d8-lhh48_default_58580cf2-ac6c-4d55-9c08-608ce2018fce_1
1638a3ba44d1   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.3   "/pause"                 7 hours ago   Up 8 hours             k8s_POD_nginx-6799fc88d8-lhh48_default_58580cf2-ac6c-4d55-9c08-608ce2018fce_1
```

---

Additional resources/reference on the topic:

- *[Ianlewis.org: Almighty pause container](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/almighty-pause-container)*
- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Isuses: Handling Deprecation of pod-infra-container-image](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/98765)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Setup: Production environment: Tools: Kubeadm: Kubelet integration: Workflow when using kubeadm init](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/kubelet-integration/#workflow-when-using-kubeadm-init)*